# C++ count if function

Tags: c++

The following returns the number 7. My problem is that im not exactly sure why 7 is the number returned. I tried running in in debug mode to break it down but 
unfortunately that did not help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool even_first( int x, int y ){
   if( (x % 2 == 0) && (y % 2 != 0) ) return true;
   if( (x % 2 != 0) && (y % 2 == 0) ) return false;
   return x < y;
}

struct BeforeValue {
    int bound;
    BeforeValue( int b ) : bound( b ) { }
    bool operator()( int value ) { return even_first( value, bound ); }
};


int main(){

list<int> my_list = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int count = count_if( my_list.begin( ), my_list.end( ), BeforeValue( 5) );

cout << count << "\n";

}
```

Comment: that it counts all the numbers below 5 and then all the even ones above it? Check which numbers cause your BeforeValue operator to return true...

Comment: Have you tried augmenting the `even_first` function to log the inputs it receives and the output it generates? It would go a long way in helping you understand what the code does.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `BeforeValue::operator()`, or make it print out the results of its comparisons?

Comment: Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To function `even_first` you pass 2 parameters: first parameter `x` is equal to successive values from `my_list` and the second parameter `y` is always `5`.

And in the even_first function we have 3 conditions:

1. `if( (x % 2 == 0) && (y % 2 != 0) ) return true;` 
   y is equal to 5 so y % 2 != 0 is always true
   x % 2 == 0 is true for: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
2. `if( (x % 2 != 0) && (y % 2 == 0) ) return false;`
   It is always false because y = 5 so y % 2 == 0 is false. We go to point 3
3. `return x < y;`
   To this statement we go only with values: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
   and it is true for: 1 and 3

So finally the even_first returns true for: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8. And the size of this set is **7**

Comment: Thank you much for your insight. Ive ran other numbers through and it makes perfect sense what it is doing. Thank You